# How to recall function in activity from listview adapter

Tags: android, listview, adapter

Can somebody help me ? I have tabhost with 4 activities A,B,C,D. Then in activity A, it has custom listview with image. If its image clicked then can call function from Activity A ? How can I solve for this case ? Thanks in advance.

Here my source of listview adapter :

```
holder.imgitem.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
                String qty="";
                if (DataProcessorResult.get(position).getSeparate().equals("INDONESIA_NATURAL") || DataProcessorResult.get(position).getSeparate().equals("INDONESIA_WOOD"))
                {
                    qty="20";
                }else {
                    if (DataProcessorResult.get(position).getSeparate().equals("DOLCEDECOR") || (DataProcessorResult.get(position).getSeparate().equals("ILBLUA")))
                    {
                        qty="10";
                    }else {
                        if (DataProcessorResult.get(position).getItemCode().substring(0, 2).equals("SF")) {qty="10";}
                        else if (DataProcessorResult.get(position).getItemCode().substring(0, 2).equals("LC")) {qty="12";}
                        else if (DataProcessorResult.get(position).getItemCode().substring(0, 2).equals("DA")) {qty="24";}
                        else if (DataProcessorResult.get(position).getItemCode().substring(0, 2).equals("SC")) {qty="48";}
                        else if (DataProcessorResult.get(position).getItemCode().substring(0, 2).equals("FS")) {qty="48";}
                        else if (DataProcessorResult.get(position).getItemCode().substring(0, 2).equals("DT")) {qty="10";}
                        else {qty="10";}
                    }
                }

                SQLiteDatabase dbinsert = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                String sqlinsert="";
                if (OtherClass.getActiveCustomerCode()!=null && !OtherClass.getActiveCustomerCode().isEmpty()) {
                    sqlinsert="INSERT INTO tcontainer (`item_code`,`CustCode`,`separate`,`qty`,`price`,`priceeuro`,`material`,`leg_color`,`nails`,`remark`,`tampil`) VALUES ("+
                             "'"+DataProcessorResult.get(position).getItemCode()+"'," +
                             "'"+OtherClass.getActiveCustomerCode()+"'," +
                             "'"+DataProcessorResult.get(position).getSeparate()+"'," +
                             "'"+qty+"'," +
                             "'0'," +
                             "'0'," +
                             "''," +
                             "''," +
                             "''," +
                             "''," +
                             "'1')";
                }else {
                    sqlinsert="INSERT INTO tcontainer (`item_code`,`CustCode`,`separate`,`qty`,`price`,`priceeuro`,`material`,`leg_color`,`nails`,`remark`,`tampil`) VALUES ("+
                             "'"+DataProcessorResult.get(position).getItemCode()+"'," +
                             "''," +
                             "'"+DataProcessorResult.get(position).getSeparate()+"'," +
                             "'"+qty+"'," +
                             "'0'," +
                             "'0'," +
                             "''," +
                             "''," +
                             "''," +
                             "''," +
                             "'1')";                    
                }
                dbinsert.execSQL(sqlinsert);
                Toast.makeText(mycontext, DataProcessorResult.get(position).getItemName()+" has been added to container", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               // HERE to call function from activity A

            }
        });
```

Comment: Doesn't `A.customMethod();` work?

Comment: off course, I have tried it before.

Comment: i mean its method work successfully

Comment: Then what do you want? Why have you posted this question?

Comment: i think you should read below answer, that's answer which I want. But I still not try yet

Answer (score 0):

1) Create an interface:

```
public interface MyInterface{
    public void myMethod();
}
```

2) Implement it in your activity:

```
 public class A_Activity extends Activity implements MyInterface{
        public void myMethod(){
            //call any method/function of your activity from here
        }
 }
```

3) Then pass your activity to ListAdater:

```
public YourAdapter extend xxxxx {
    private MyInterface myInterface;

    public MyAdapter(MyInterface myInterface){
        this.myInterface = myInterface;
    }
}
```

4) Finally, in your adapter you can call your activity functions by:  `myInterface.myMethod();`